# Using apache http client to upload file using multipart to spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, httpclient, multipart

I have an spring boot application that has end point like this

```
@PostMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<FileUploadResponseDto> upload(@RequestPart("details") FileUploadDto fileUploadDto,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
  try {
      return ResponseEntity.ok( fileUploadService.uploadFile(fileUploadDto,file));
  }catch (Exception e){
      return ResponseEntity.status(406).body(new FileUploadResponseDto(false,e.getMessage()));
  }
};
```

When using postman everything works fine.
This is postman example
[image]

But when i try to use http apache client the spring boot returns application/octet-stream is not supported

[image]

What Am I doing wrong here ?

EDIT

code apache client

```
String json = mapToJson(Map.of("name",(String)file[1],"lastname",    

(String)file[2],"createTime",(String)file[3]));
       final MultipartEntityBuilder builder  =                               
       MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

       builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
       builder.addTextBody("details",json,ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
       builder.addBinaryBody("file",(File)file[4],ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,((File)file[4]).getName());

       final HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://"+host+":"+port+"/api/v1/upload/");
       try(CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {

           final HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
           httpPost.setEntity(entity);
           HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);

           System.out.println(httpResponse);

       } catch (IOException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
```

This is the message/response I get

HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 415  [Accept: application/json, application/*+json, Content-Type: application/json, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Date: Sun, 11 Feb 2024 22:02:27 GMT, Keep-Alive: timeout=60, Connection: keep-alive] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/json,Chunked: true]}}

SOLUTION:

I am not sure why is this happening, but I had this mode configured           builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

and when I debugged inside spring, request would come little bit messed up, for example 'details' part would not even have content-type it would be null.

then i switched the mode to            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.STRICT);
and then in request.getParts(), 'details' would have content-type application json

Comment: Couple additional items needed here. First, please copy the code here instead of using a screenshot, and please include the segment of code that sets the root Content-Type header. Second, please provide the full error as well. It is not uncommon for the initial error to say one thing, when the root of the problem is further down the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why is this happening, but I had this mode configured builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

and when I debugged inside spring, request would come little bit messed up, for example 'details' part would not even have content-type it would be null.

then i switched the mode to builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.STRICT); and then in request.getParts(), 'details' would have content-type application json